# Convertion from a uint16 to uint8

Tags: c, compression, type-conversion, stm32

Does anybody know how I can do a correct conversion from a uint16 to a uint8 in a C program for my STM32F091?

I thought that it was like this:

```
uint16_t Test = 0x565;
uint8_t Test2 = (uint8_t)Test;
```

But that doesn't work very well, so does anyone has a suggestion?

---

[update from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36725474/convertion-from-a-16uint-to-8uint/36725539#comment61035367_36725474):]

I use a potentiometer that has a minimum value of 0x0 and a maximum value of 0xFFF. Test must have the value of ADC1->DR (this is a value from the ADC in the STM32F0)

Comment: What type are "16uint" and  "8uint"? You text uses different types. What do you mean with "doesn't work well"? Why? In which sense?

Comment: You cannot get a quart into a pint pot.

Comment: Because of overflow? It is very likely the case.

Comment: @EdHeal: Could you please express this in metric units? ;-)

Comment: Sorry - there is not a metric version of the proverb

Comment: Do you aware that casting to smaller sized integer could potentially cause data lost?

Comment: Well i made a program that has a uint16 output, i want to convert this to a uint8 value because i have only 8 LEDs and want to show it like that.

Comment: How do your 8 LEDs relate to the Test and Test2 values?

Comment: I repeat: Please clarify what you want to achieve. If it is really that you ask how to "compress" 16 bits to 8 bits without information loss, you should redo information theory basics.

Comment: I use a potentiometer that has a minimum value of 0x0 and a maximum value of 0xFFF. Test must have the value of ADC1->DR (this is a value from the ADC in the STM32F0)

Comment: @Olaf it is true that i want to compress without information lost

Comment: So please redo the basics. This is impossible.

Comment: @Sandreerius you cannot compress the data without information lost in this case. But you still can map the data with precision lost. For example: Test >> 8

Comment: The magic word is "scaling". Just apply the "rule of three"/"rule of proprtion".

Comment: @Ian: precision loss == information loss. OP clearly stated he does not want to loose information, thus no solution possible.

Comment: Alternatively you could implement different modes of display: Scaling (see my last comment), Clipping, by either clip the peaks or clip the sinks or a "bit" of both. The latter could also be called "Window"-mode. :-)

Comment: @Olaf yes, but if the final aim is just to show the value in 8 LEDs, then he still can do that. He just need to aware that precision/information lost is to be expected since he put 12-bit to 8-bit.

Comment: @Ian thanx for the tip , now it works fine i did the next: Test >> 4 and know it works fine with my 8 LEDs

Comment: Exccuse me for the miss understanding sometimes because my english is not very well , i said i didn't want information lost but with that i mean was what Ian told :)

Comment: @Ian: .I just argue in the constraints given. And OP clearly stated she does not want information loss. But apparently now it is accepted. Which shows he should make up her mind before continuing with the project.

Comment: @Olaf true, strictly given the constraint he stated (which the OP himself probably didn't understand), I agree with you. It is right to say that I read "in between the lines" - which apperantly is what the OP really wants though he wrongly stated his intention.

Comment: @Sandeerius You can show that Ian's answer helped by upvoting it and clicking the checkmark next to it. Thanks.

Comment: For completeness: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication#Rule_of_Three some basics ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**

You cannot compress the data without information lost in this case. Since your data range from ADC is 0x000 to 0xFFF - there is no way for you to represent the data perfectly without information/precision lost in uint8 byte whose range is only from 0x00 to 0xFF

But you still can map the data *with* precision lost. For example:

```
uint8_t Test2 = (unsigned)(Test >> 4);
```

Will cause you to map every 16 range to a single value:

```
0-15 -> 0
16-31 -> 1
32-47 -> 2
//and so on
```

Since you only have 8 LEDs anyway, you could use uint8 byte to control the LED - though you will lose precision of the real value, but you are still able to represent the range of the value (per unit of 16) *correctly* with your 8 LEDs (since you *only* have 8 LEDs anyway)

**Original:**

The case is very likely cause by overflow when you cast bigger-sized uint16 data type to smaller-sized uint8:

```
uint16_t Test = 0x565;
uint8_t Test2 = (uint8_t)Test; //Test2 value is only 0x65, 0x500 is missing
```

The casting causes the most significant byte value (0x500) to be truncated.

Comment: But won't the OP already be aware of the data loss?

Comment: @HappyCoder might or might not be. But judging from the code alone, it is more likely that he is not aware of.

Comment: Sigh, what's with the SO today. Downvote for no clear reason. While we can help new user to "teach to fish", downvote on the answer is chosen instead.

Comment: Gave you an upvote, but may I recommend removing the first version of the answer. It adds no value. Scaling the value to provide the full range is the correct answer, and should be right at the top.

Comment: You probably got the downvote for the initial `>>8`...

Comment: @user3386109 suggestion accepted. Thanks.

Comment: @alk ah yes, I just aware of my mistake too - but the downvote came before that. Corrected.

Comment: `Test >> 4` is implementation defined for negative values on this architecture (32 bit `int`). Correct would be `(unsigned)Test >> 4` (`unsigned` is garanteed to have at least the same width as `uint16_t`).

Comment: Note: Some rounding scheme would actually yield better approximation.

Comment: @Olaf adjusted, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @alk: Yes, but you know this is not only read by OP, so I think adding a note is strongly recommended. The cast will not change the machine code (presuming the standard AAPCS at least).